# Can not add reference to COM lib - no such tab in reference manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I need to add a reference to MS Excel into my solution, but I simply can not find where to do it. In the Reference manager (on Right Click on solution / Add / Add Reference I simply get this [image: ref manager view]

Where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Expand browse on the left hand side? Or try and type something  in the search box in the upper right

Comment: The kind of project matters.  This is what you'd see in a .NETCore project, they don't encourage using COM since it doesn't make sense.  The kind of machine that supports Excel interop always has the full version of the framework available.